# Resize button inside UIToolbar

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a barbutton inside my Toolbar and I'm trying to increase the height of toolbar along with the barbutton. I was able to increase the size of the Toolbar using the following code. But I'm still unable to increase the height of the Barbutton inside it. Any ideas?

```
Declaration in .h

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *viewLogToolbar;

Code in .m

    CGRect frameBar = viewLogToolbar.frame;
    frameBar.size.height = 75;
    viewLogToolbar.frame=frameBar;
```

This only increases size of UIToolbar, but the similar code doesnt work for the barbutton.

Declarations of my UIBarButton property and action

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *viewLogOut;

- (IBAction)viewLog:(id)sender;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For increaing UIBarButtonItem size assign UIbutton to its customView property as below :

```
UIButton *yourbutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
yourbutton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
[yourbutton addTarget:self action:@selector(YOUR_METHOD:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourbutton];
```

EDIT : You can pass bar button it toolbar as :

```
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: barButtonItem,nil];

[YOUR_TOOLBAR setItems:items animated:NO];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I already have a property and action defined for my UIbarbutton which is inside UIToolbar like @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *viewLogOut;- (IBAction)viewLog:(id)sender; How should I use this code along with this?

Comment: You can add that method for the UIButton event and then assign this UIButton to UIBarButtonItem. It will work fine.

Comment: Here you are creating a custom UIBarButton. My UIBarButton is already made up inside the UIToolBar. Even if I follow this approach how will I add my UIBarButton inside UIToolBar?

Comment: How to add title to the new UIBarButton in the toolbar? setTitle, titleLabel doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @Gamerlegend you need to set the title of the UIButton and then it will be displayed in the UIBarButtonItem as UIButton is assigned to UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSMutableArray *buttons=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

    UIButton *reportBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
   // [reportBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnReportClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    reportBtn.frame = CGRectMake(330.00, 300.0, 90.0, 30.0);
    [reportBtn setTitle:@"Report"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [reportBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    reportBtn.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:13.0];
    //reportBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:65.0/255.0 green:105.0/255.0 blue:225.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    [reportBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbarbtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:reportBtn];

    UIBarButtonItem *repoBarbtn =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:reportBtn];
    repoBarbtn.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
    [buttons addObject:repoBarbtn];
    [repoBarbtn release];
```

Try this code once......may be it will help you..put this code in viewdidload or some other method.

Comment: I dont want a custom button, I want to increase the size of my button inside UIToolbar. I already have a property and action defined for my button inside UIToolbar like @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *viewLogOut;- (IBAction)viewLog:(id)sender; The frame or CGRect option doesnt come with either of the two.